# Minmax normalization cast away the complex part?

Tags: python, numpy, normalization, complex-numbers

I am currently trying to normalize an numpy.ndarray containing complex numbers, but for some reason is my implementation casting away the complex part.. Why?...

```
def numpy_minmax(X):
    xmin =  X.min()
    print X.min()
    print X.max()
    return (2*(X - xmin) / (X.max() - xmin)-1)*0.9
```

Comment: What do you expect the minimum of complex numbers be? Which is smaller, `3+4j` or `4+3j`?  Yes, NumPy ignores the imaginary part. You can take it into account with `np.imag(X).min()` but to begin with, what "minimax normalization" even supposed to mean for complex numbers?

Comment: How does Neural network handles complex numbers?.. The normalization was done for the input of a neural network.. how can i normalize it?

Comment: What is for you normalization?

Comment: Good point.. Is there a different way normalize such that it range between

Comment: ndarray containing complex numbers

Answer (score 1):

The minimum or maximum of complex numbers is an undefined concept. This is why NumPy ignores the imaginary part when taking max or min of an array.

Generally, normalization consists of *centering* and *scaling*.

A natural notion of center of an array of complex numbers is the center of the smallest disk containing them. But this (the *Chebyshev center*) is somewhat difficult to compute. A simpler way to center is to take the smallest axes-aligned rectangle containing the numbers. This involves looking at max/min of real and imaginary parts separately:

```
a = (np.real(X).min() + np.real(X).max())/2.0
b = (np.imag(X).min() + np.imag(X).max())/2.0
Y = X - complex(a, b)
```

Next, the scaling. Looks like you want the absolute values of the numbers to be at most 0.9. This can be arranged by using the maximum of absolute values of elements of Y.

```
return 0.9*Y/np.abs(Y).max()
```

This is not the only way one could proceed; but to me the above appears to be the most straightforward adaptation of your code to the complex case.